IvParameterSpec(byte[]) is being defined based on hardcoded values dexguard issue
We are trying to integrate dexguard on our application. while we generate the protected .apk file and uploaded to app sweep we got an issue
IvParameterSpec(byte[]) is being defined based on hardcoded values


Block cipher algorithms (e.g. AES), when operating in modes such as
CBC and OFB, require an initialization vector (IV) as an initial input
to the cipher. The IV does not have to be kept secret, but it should
not be reused or predictable. Therefore, IV should not be defined
based on hardcoded values. Make sure that IVs are generated using a
cryptographically secure random number generator before each
encryption.


from org.bouncycastle library. We are using library
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.68'

I added below line on the dexguard rules and progurad rules files, but not working
-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**

